# Return static content in case of null (Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, null, thymeleaf

I have a html template with many th: definitions. I would like to return it with various URL patterns. But I don't always need all these definitions. For example in case of "/one" I would like to change the title this way:

```
@RequestMapping("/one")
public String one(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "ONE");
    return "template";
}
```

In case of "/two" I don't want to change the title. But if I skip `addAtrribute()` it will return nothing instead of the "default" static content provided by the Designer.

How could I change this th definition

```
<title th:text="${pageTitle}">SPRING BOOT</title>
```

that if pageTitle is null (no `model.addAttribute()`) it shows SPRING BOOT instead of nothing without hardcode it in the else branch?

I was browsing many of threads related to thymeleaf and null, but everywhere I have found solutions that in case of null returns **something else** instead of the static content. For example:

```
th:text="${pageTitle} ?: '(no content)'"
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? On page `/one` to have custom title from model and on `/two` to have the default title `SPRING BOOT`?

Comment: Exactly. But it was just an example. So sadly creating a new html without th definitions is not a solution. I need something that "ignores itself" in case of null.

Comment: The `(no content)` and the `SPRING BOOT` pieces of text from the question are both hard-coded into your Thymeleaf template, right? In that sense they are both static content.

Comment: You are right. Under static content I meant the text between ```<title>``` and ```</title>```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<title th:text="${pageTitle}?:'SPRING BOOT'">This gets replaced by Thymeleaf so it does not matter what you put here</title>
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, use:

```
<title th:if="${pageTitle}" th:text="${pageTitle}">SPRING BOOT</title>  
<title th:unless="${pageTitle}">SPRING BOOT</title>
```

The first tag will be used when `pageTitle` is not `null`. If is it `null`, the 2nd tag will be used. As there is no `th:text` there, the contents of the tag will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to hardcode it. I want to return whatever is in between the tags. In this way you suggested if the designer change the title from SPRING BOOT to LITTLE POPPY it remains SPRING BOOT on my side.

Comment: But why? The designer should be free to change what is between the tags and if `pageTitle` is not defined when running the app, you will get SPRING BOOT.

Comment: I don't insist on getting SPRING BOOT. I want to get that is actually in the tags (whatever it is).

Comment: Updated answer with a possible alternative.

Comment: Almost perfect. Could it be changed somehow in one tag?

Comment: Not that I know.